# Subdomain Magento Multistore Internal Server Error

Tags: magento, subdomain, internal-server-error, multistore

I'm using **Magento CE 1.8.** I've read through articles dealing with Magento server errors, but didn't find anything that fits my situation.

I've set up two additional stores (website, store, and store views) using parked domains, which work fine. I just set up two additional stores using subdomains, and and running into an 'Internal Server Error' on all pages except the home page for these two new stores using subdomains.

I followed this tutorial... https://www.siteground.com/tutorials/magento/magento-multistore.htm
except for the part that says add this code...

```
$mageRunCode = ‘sgtest’;
$mageRunType = ‘website’;
```

before the last line in the `index.php` file.

That looks to be outdated, because the index.php already has the following code in place for multiple storefronts...

```
/* Store or website code */
$mageRunCode = isset($_SERVER['MAGE_RUN_CODE']) 
    ? $_SERVER['MAGE_RUN_CODE'] 
    : '';
/* Run store or run website */
$mageRunType = isset($_SERVER['MAGE_RUN_TYPE'])
    ? $_SERVER['MAGE_RUN_TYPE'] 
    : 'store';
```

So I just filled in my store code. Now, the front page of each subdomain store works fine. But if I try to navigate away from the home page, I get this...

> *Internal Server Error*
>
> *The server encountered an internal error or misconfiguration and was unable to complete your request. Please contact the server
>   administrator, webmaster@ninedays.sidekart.com and inform them of the
>   time the error occurred, and anything you might have done that may
>   have caused the error. More information about this error may be
>   available in the server error log.*
>
> *Additionally, a 500 Internal Server Error error was encountered while trying to use an ErrorDocument to handle the request.*

There's no error log on the server for me to look at, so it's difficult to determine the issue.

All file and folder permissions have been set using a magento-cleanup.php script that sets all folders to 755 and all files to 644.

Answer (score 0):

Replace :

> ### MAGENTO_ROOT
>
> ```
> /** nativ code: define('MAGENTO_ROOT', getcwd());` */
> define('MAGENTO_ROOT', '/absolute/path/to/legacy/website');`
> ```

---

> ### $_SERVER['MAGE_RUN_CODE']
>
> ```
> /** nativ code : $mageRunCode = isset($_SERVER['MAGE_RUN_CODE']) ? $_SERVER['MAGE_RUN_CODE'] : ''; */
> $mageRunCode = isset($_SERVER['MAGE_RUN_CODE']) ? $_SERVER['MAGE_RUN_CODE'] : 'your_store_code_here';
> ```

---

> ### $_SERVER['MAGE_RUN_TYPE']
>
> ```
> /** nativ code: $mageRunType = isset($_SERVER['MAGE_RUN_TYPE']) ? $_SERVER['MAGE_RUN_TYPE'] : 'store'; */
> $mageRunType = isset($_SERVER['MAGE_RUN_TYPE']) ? $_SERVER['MAGE_RUN_TYPE'] : 'website';
> ```

before execute `Mage::run($mageRunCode, $mageRunType);` in `index.php` file.

Comment: I added that to the index.php that I copied into the root of the additional store, not the index.php file in the root of my base Magento install. Is that the correct way? Now my browser shows: Parse error: syntax error, unexpected '' (T_ENCAPSED_AND_WHITESPACE), expecting identifier (T_STRING) or variable (T_VARIABLE) or number (T_NUM_STRING) in /home/sidekart/public_html/ninedays/index.php on line 78Line 78 is the first line of the following:<br />`if (isset($_SERVER['MAGE_IS_DEVELOPER_MODE'])) {
    Mage::setIsDeveloperMode(true);
}`

Comment: P.S. Sorry for the sloppy comment. I'm new to StackExchange and the comment format.

Comment: since what you suggested was giving me the syntax error, I reverted to my old index.php and simply removed the .htaccess in the root of my additional (subdomain) store. Now it works fine. The .htaccess in the root of my Magento install is still active, so I think I happened upon a solution.